# cannot bring up show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the button that should bring up the show page
**edit - changed**

```
 <%= button_to 'Show', post_path(p) %>
```

This does bring up a button but I get an error when I click it:

```
No route matches [POST] "/posts/3"
```

I am confused why a POST request is being sent. (Note "post_path" refers to a "Post" controller/model).

In my routes I have

```
resources :posts
```

The button is on the index page and I have an iterator to make an edit button for each Post. 
Here is my "show" action:

```
def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Thanks for your help.

***edit: the code is here: https://github.com/MaxPleaner/feature_tester***

Comment: Actually what do you want: to edit the post or show the post?

Comment: can you post your rake routes detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails will construct a form around `button` elements so that they work properly, and forms by default will use `method: :post`.

If it's just a link to the show page, it should be a link. You can style the link to look like a button if you really wish.